# Toshiba Portégé with Windows 7 not recognising DVD Drive - possible Driver issue?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, toshiba-laptop

I’m trying to fix a friend’s laptop.  The DVD driver is corrupted, so the optical drive doesn’t even show up as an option in Windows Explorer.

#### Failed attempts so far…

- Microsoft Update seems to think the driver is up-to-date and okay—even though Device Manager shows a problem with it.  (The little yellow `!` icon is visible.)
- I tried uninstalling the driver and rebooting. This *theoretically* forces the automatic fetching & installation of the missing driver.  It simply reinstalled the previous driver… along with the previous problem.
- I also tried the vendor’s website (for both the laptop’s and optical drive’s manufacturers) with no luck.
- **Laptop:** Toshiba Portégé R705
- **OS:** Windows 7 Home Premium
- **Optical Drive:** MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ892ES

---

#### Questions

- Does a safe, 3rd-party driver provider exist?  (If so, where?)
- Do you have any recommended procedures that aren’t listed in my previous attempts?

Comment: why do you discount the idea that the **Drive** itself is out of order?

Comment: I haven’t.  I just wanted to rule out the software drivers first, because I remembered that I used to be able to do that relatively quickly.  Not so much, any more. :P  In any case, you have a good point, and I appreciate the reminder.  Will look into it.

Comment: Want to find out of the drive works?  Boot to a DVD.  Better yet, boot to a linux LiveCD.  If the system boots, and the drive continues to operate nominally, then you *know* it is a software issue within Windows.  It could even be an upper/lower filter issue within Windows.    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314060

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed!**

Turns out a simple BIOS update did the trick.

I don’t understand how the old BIOS—with which the drive previously worked—stopped working in the first place.

But eventually I found a utility called TOSHIBA SERVICE CENTER, which updates covers a few of Windows Update’s blind spots: Toshiba software, the BIOS, and a few others.

Thanks for your help, @Sathya, @Bon Gart!  I hope your answers are useful to other readers.  (Or, perhaps to me in the future. ☺)

Comment: Hi @Zearin, good to hear you solved your problem! You can mark your own answer as accepted if you wish, by clicking the outline of the check-mark underneath the vote count :)